# UnicodeDecodeError while trying to change points into commas in Excel

Tags: python, excel, encoding, utf-8

I'm currently trying to run following code:

```
import csv

with open("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\stu21617.rw2.xlsx", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile: 
    with open("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\jens\\komma.xlsx", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        tabel = []
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = ';')
        for rij in csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ';'):
            writer.writerow(rij.replace('.', ','))
```

But I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? `.xlsx` suggests that you are reading an Excel file directly, but excel files are not csv's and one wouldn't expect them to be utf-8 encoded.

Comment: I'm trying to run the code through a jupyter notebook and how do I change an Excel file into a csv?

Comment: Excel workbooks can get complicated (they tend to be fairly free-form) and there isn't a single generic way to get useful information out of them. Much like scraping a web page, you need to look at the excel file to decide what to grab from it. There are various python tools you can use (see for instance http://www.python-excel.org/). Or maybe you just do the csv export manually from excel.

Comment: I now saved my file as a csv file encoded with utf-8 and I get an other error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\jens\\stu21617.rw2.xlsx'

Comment: I fixed the Permission Error as well but now I get the error that list has no attribute replace.

Comment: I fixed everything now, tis is my final code:
import csv
with open("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\jens\\stu21617.rw2.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    with open("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\jens\\komma.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        tabel = []
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = ';')
        for rij in csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ';'):
            tabel.append(rij)
        for rij in tabel:
            for i in range(0, len(rij)):
                rij[i].replace('.', ',')
        for rij in tabel:
            writer.writerow(rij)

Comment: the problem is that the points aren't changed by commas

Comment: Update your question with the new code so we can view it more easily.

Comment: Also, can you post an example of the incoming csv? We don't even need the real data if its something sensitive. Just a reproduction of the first few lines to experiment with.